# Gallai Identity 2

Tags: graph-theory

My goal is to prove that that the size of the minimum vertex cover plus the size of the maximum set of independent vertices is equal to the order of the graph. I have already shown that $S$ is a set of independent vertices if and only if the set $V(G) - S$ is a vertex cover. Here, $V(G)$ is the vertex set of the graph G. Here is how I started my proof of Gallai's identity:

Suppose M is the minimum vertex cover of G. Then $V(G) - M$ is a set of independent vertices. Hence $|M| + |V(G) - M| = |G|$. Now how do I prove that $|V(G) - M|$ is the size of the maximum set of independent vertices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already proven the hard part. You need to explicitly use the fact that $M$ is minimum to finish the proof.

Assume to the contrary that $|V(G)-M|$ is *not* the max size, ie., there is an independent set $S$ with $|S|>|V(G)-M|$.
Then $V(G)-S$ is a vertex cover with $|V(G)-S| < |M|$, contradicting the fact that $M$ is minimum.